# Controlling log with short-hand if-then-else in python

Tags: python

I am trying to control my logs using short-hand `if-else`, because it looks elegant in a one-liner, but I notice I need to implement the `else` flow as well.

```
Class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.log_enabled = False       # To enable/disable logs
        ...

    def test(self):
        ...
        print "Command is being executed..." if self.log_enabled == True else pass
        ...
```

If I put `pass` at `else`, then it is an error.  Any way to cleanly implement this, either using `if-else` or other methods?

Comment: That's not how the conditional expression works. Also you should consider using the builtin logging facilities.

Comment: just do `else '' ` to print nothing

Comment: @RNar: Nothing but a blank line, which isn't what you want.

Comment: Why not use that beautiful logger module python gives you?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Thanks. I will take a look at the logging module. It looks like a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

You're telling it what to print. `pass` isn't something you can print. You can print the empty string, though.

```
print "Command is being executed..." if self.log_enabled else '',
```

However, it looks like you're just trying to shoehorn a ternary operator into your code, where such a strategy leaves your code noticeably worse. Just use the traditional structure:

```
if self.log_enabled:
    print "Command is being executed..."
```

Comment: The `else ''` option still prints a newline.

Comment: Added a comma, now it just prints a space. That's the best I can do without `sys.stdout` or `from __future__ import print_function`, and the proper solution is to ditch the ternary operator entirely anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
def log_it(self, message, *args):
    if self.log_enabled:
        print message % args

def test(self):
    log_it("Command is being executed...")
    log_it("A number less than 3 and greater than 1 is %d", 2)
```

But if this is a non-trivial project, you should just use the regular python logging classes.